# What is the role of dogs in Hinduism?

Tags: belief, animals, bhairava

In Hinduism dogs have a great importance lord Kalabhairva's mount is a dog.can one features exactly the

**Importance of dogs in Hinduism**

and

**How are they even related to gods**

Comment: Dogs are often not liked much in Hindu Scriptures. And please do tell the story of "dog becoming sun god".

Comment: from where i read there are no refrences given sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: So as you can see dogs are not considered as important part of the Vedic religion. What more do u want to see in the answer? Are u looking for that story? @Fiercelord

Comment: Well in satarudriya i have read that lord rudra is called as lord of dogs and one who is in the face of dog so sorry i can not totally take it as per dharma shastras.

Comment: You mean this- "namah shabhyah shvapatibhyah cha vo namaha"? But then in Sri Rudram Lord Shiva is praised as the lords of everything even as lords of burglars, of thieves (stenAnAm pataye namaha). So does that mean thieves are important too in Hinduism? Sri Rudram is describing Lord Shiva as the Brahman, as everything, as lords of everything. @Fiercelord

Comment: i knew this type of comment may come.:) well as you have seen i have +1 your answer because at some instance you are right but just for a slight have a look to **Sarama** goddess — https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/my confusion is clearing i may post a diffrent question(not this one) but my new curiocity and you are always welcome@rickross. well my intention was a bit clear but what is left you will see in next question

Comment: as you see/may know too if vedas don't lead dogs down i have no problem with other because i understanded why they are so and in my next question i am gooing to clear it.;)

Comment: @Fiercelord The Sarama goddess link u shared is not working. Chk it. :)

Comment: Related: [Did the story of Mahabharata start (and end) with a dog?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13959/did-the-story-of-mahabharata-start-and-end-with-a-dog)

Comment: ooops... sorry@rickross here's the link:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarama

Answer (score 6):

Well a dog does not have much role to play in Hinduism (at least generally and superficially speaking). The scriptures, specially the Smritis, talk very badly about them.

See the following verse for example. And, such verses are found in every Smriti texts.

> **An ancestral offering is ruined if it is seen by a dog**, a Candala or
>   an outcaste. Therefore, he should offer it in an enclosed place; 
>   alternatively he should scatter sesame seeds over the offering,
>
> **Gautama Smriti 15.28**

And, the following:

> **Gods do not eat the food of a man who keeps dogs**, who is married to a Sudra woman, who is controlled by his wife, or who lets his
>   wife’s lover remain in his house.
>
> **Vashishta Dharma Sutras 14.15**

..................................

So, according to the last verse, all people of today's time, who keep pet dogs, are worshiping Gods in vain. However, it is talking about the Dvijas (the twice borns) who have kept the Vedic fire in their homes.

**Updating the answer:**

In the following Vedic Mantra a dog is symbolically linked with jealousy (which is one of the [Shadaripus](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16527/shadripu-in-hindu-texts); the six enemies of a man). The Mantra then asks Lord Indra (who's identified as the [lord of the divine mind](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17860/4732)) to kill these 6 enemies for us. This Mantra is symbolic as it maps one animal (or bird) to one of the Shadaripus.

> UlukayAtum ShushulukayAtum Jahi **SvayAtum** Uta KokayAtum SuparnayAtum
>   Uta Grdhrayatum Drshadeva Pra Mrna Raksha Indra.
>
> Oh Indra! kill the delusion (owl), anger (wolf), jealousy (dog), the
>   lust (chakravAka), arrogance (eagle) and the greed (vulture).
>
> **Atharva Veda 8.4.22**

Another reference is of Yama's two dogs, who are his messengers. These dogs are mentioned in Rig Veda's Yama Sukta.

> ati drava sArameyau svAnau catur aksau sabalau sAdhunA patha |
>  athA
>   pitrn suvidatrAgum upehi yamena ye sadhamAdham madanti||
>
> 10.Run by a good path past the two-eyed   sons of Sarama, the four-eyed brindled  guard-dogs; then    approach the bountiful manes who rejoice at
>   the   same    feast as Yama.
>
> 12.Broad-nosed    and takers-of-life these two dogs,   messengers of Yama wander among mankind; may these two give us back here to-day
>   auspicious    life that   we may see the sun.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a single Smriti illuminating.

Comment: i am not qualified to talk about the sages. But Parashara, Atri Vashishta, Yajnavalkya have Smritis attributed to them. @Tamas.

Comment: Hmm, I have not concluded finally, I think these Smritis might be true. Truth seems bitter usually. But Smritis don't seem illuminating or something which could remove pAshas of pashus.

Comment: I think these Smritis are for general pashus, one who has been initiated on the path of Parmeshvara doesn't need to discriminate between any creature be it a dog or Shudra/Outcaste.

Comment: Yes that's my opinion too (pashus). But all scriptures are not meant to do everything. Smritis' purpose might be to train the pashus. But they are part of the Kalpa sutras which are part of the Vedangas. So, that's how they are more close to the Vedas than any other scriptures. @Tamas.

Comment: IMO, even Vedas too although the highest authority, are just to train the pashus to tread the unknown path. Ultimate truth surpasses any kind of rituals, religions, books etc.

Comment: I dont know why to say or not but these verses make me very unconfortable. Hinduism recongnizes divnity of all beings ..

Comment: And I am not quoting from scriptures of Buddhism. I am quoting from scriptures of Hinduism only @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Answer (score 3):

I got an intresting story:—

> Vaishampayana said: "Then Shakra,
>   causing the firmament and the Earth
>   to be filled by a loud sound, came to
>   the son of Pritha on a car and asked
>   him to ascend it. Beholding his
>   brothers fallen on the Earth, king
>   Yudhishthira the just said unto that
>   deity of a 1,000 eyes these words:
>   ‘My brothers have all dropped down
>   here. They must go with me.
>   Without them by me I do not wish
>   to go to Heaven, O lord of all the
>   deities. The delicate princess
>   (Draupadi) deserving of every
>   comfort, O Purandara, should go with
>   us. It behoveth thee to permit this.’
>
> "Shakra said, ‘Thou shalt behold thy
>   brothers in Heaven. They have
>   reached it before thee. Indeed, thou
>   shalt see all of them there, with
>   Krishna. Do not yield to grief, O
>   chief of the Bharatas. Having cast off
>   their human bodies they have gone
>   there, O chief of Bharata’s race. As
>   regards thee, it is ordained that
>   thou shalt go thither in this very
>   body of thine.’
>
> **"Yudhishthira said, ‘This dog, O lord
>   of the Past and the Present, is
>   exceedingly devoted to me. He
>   should go with me. My heart is full
>   of compassion for him.’**
>
> "Shakra said, ‘Immortality and a
>   condition equal to mine, O king,
>   prosperity extending in all
>   directions, and high success, and all
>   the felicities of Heaven, thou hast
>   won today. Do thou cast off this dog.
>   In this there will be no cruelty.’
>
> "Yudhishthira said, ‘O thou of a
>   1,000 eyes. O thou that art of
>   righteous behaviour, it is
>   exceedingly difficult for one that is
>   of righteous behaviour to perpetrate
>   an act that is unrighteous. I do not
>   desire that union with prosperity for
>   which I shall have to cast off one
>   that is devoted to me.’
>
> "Indra said, ‘There is no place in
>   Heaven for persons with dogs.
>   Besides, the (deities called)
>   Krodhavasas take away all the merits
>   of such persons. Reflecting on this,
>   act, O king Yudhishthira the just. Do
>   thou abandon this dog. There is no
>   cruelty in this.’
>
> **"Yudhishthira said, ‘It has been said
>   that the abandonment of one that is
>   devoted is infinitely sinful. It is
>   equal to the sin that one incurs by
>   slaying a Brahmana.** Hence, O great
>   Indra, I shall not abandon this dog
>   today from desire of my happiness.
>   Even this is my vow steadily
>   pursued, that I never give up a
>   person that is terrified, nor one that
>   is devoted to me, nor one that seeks
>   my protection, saying that he is
>   destitute, nor one that is afflicted,
>   nor one that has come to me, nor
>   one that is weak in protecting
>   oneself, nor one that is solicitous of
>   life. I shall never give up such a one
>   till my own life is at an end.’
>
> "Indra said, ‘Whatever gifts, or
>   sacrifices spread out, or libations
>   poured on the sacred fire, are seen
>   by a dog, are taken away by the
>   Krodhavasas. Do thou, therefore,
>   abandon this dog. By abandoning
>   this dog thou wilt attain to the
>   region of the deities. Having
>   abandoned thy brothers and Krishna,
>   thou hast, O hero, acquired a region
>   of felicity by thy own deeds. Why art
>   thou so stupefied? Thou hast
>   renounced everything. Why then
>   dost thou not renounce this dog?’
>
> "Yudhishthira said, ‘This is well
>   known in all the worlds that there is
>   neither friendship nor enmity with
>   those that are dead. When my
>   brothers and Krishna died, I was
>   unable to revive them. Hence it was
>   that I abandoned them. I did not,
>   however, abandon them as long as
>   they were alive. To frighten one that
>   has sought protection, the slaying of
>   a woman, the theft of what belongs
>   to a Brahmana, and injuring a
>   friend, each of these four, O Shakra,
>   is I think equal to the abandonment
>   of one that is devoted.’"
>
> Vaishampayana continued: "Hearing
>   these words of king Yudhishthira the
>   just, (the dog became transformed
>   into) the deity of Righteousness,
>   who, well pleased, said these words
>   unto him in a sweet voice fraught
>   with praise.
>
> "Dharma said: ‘Thou art well born, O
>   king of kings, and possessed of the
>   intelligence and the good conduct of
>   Pandu. Thou hast compassion for all
>   creatures, O Bharata, of which this is
>   a bright example. Formerly, O son,
>   thou wert once examined by me in
>   the woods of Dwaita, where thy
>   brothers of great prowess met with
>   (an appearance of) death.
>   Disregarding both thy brothers
>   Bhima and Arjuna, thou didst wish
>   for the revival of Nakula from thy
>   desire of doing good to thy (step-)
>   mother.**On the present occasion,
>   thinking the dog to be devoted to
>   thee, thou hast renounced the very
>   car of the celestials instead of
>   renouncing him. Hence. O king,
>   there is no one in Heaven that is
>   equal to thee. Hence, O Bharata,
>   regions of inexhaustible felicity are
>   thine. Thou hast won them, O chief
>   of the Bharatas, and thine is a
>   celestial and high goal.’"**

source:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17003.htm

> Dattatreya figure has four dogs symbolizing 4 vedas

Answer (score 3):

As has already been delineated about the position of dogs according to several scriptures, it can be unanimously accepted that keeping them **at home** can render rituals ineffective. But according to Bṛihat Samhitā, Chapter 62,

> A dog three of whose legs have five nails and the right forefoot six, whose lips and muzzle are red, which has the gait of a lion, smells the ground while running, has a shaggy tail, eyes like those of a bear, ears handing and soft, such a dog being kept in a house promises ere-long great prosperity to the owner. —v1. 
> A bitch with five nails on each foot, six on the left forefoot , with eyes surrounded by white rings, with crooked tail and having brown color and hanging ears, protects the country if she is properly nurtured. —v2.

it seems that keeping a particular breed might turn out to be favorable also. On squaring these contrary verses with the dictums of other scriptures, it seems that a particular breed of a dog can be kept (possible somewhere outside the home) while ensuring that it doesn't stumble upon performance of nitya, naimittika & kāmya karma-s.